# How do I position my UIScrollView's image properly when switching orientation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how best to reposition my `UIScrollView`'s image view (I have a gallery kind of app going right now, similar to Photos.app, specifically when you're viewing a single image) when the orientation switches from portrait to landscape or vice-versa.

I know my best bet is to manipulate the `contentOffset` property, but I'm not sure what it should be changed to.

I've played around a lot, and it seems like for whatever reason `128` works really well. In my `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method for my view controller I have:

```
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)) {
        CGPoint newContentOffset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;

        if (newContentOffset.x >= 128) {
            newContentOffset.x -= 128.0;
        }
        else {
            newContentOffset.x = 0.0;
        }

        newContentOffset.y += 128.0;

        self.scrollView.contentOffset = newContentOffset;
    }
    else {
        CGPoint newContentOffset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;

        if (newContentOffset.y >= 128) {
            newContentOffset.y -= 128.0;
        }
        else {
            newContentOffset.y = 0.0;
        }

        newContentOffset.x += 128.0;

        self.scrollView.contentOffset = newContentOffset;
    }
```

And it works *pretty well*. I hate how it's using a magic number though, and I have no idea where this would come from.

Also, whenever I zoom the image I have it set to stay centred (just like Photos.app does):

```
- (void)centerScrollViewContent {
    // Keep image view centered as user zooms
    CGRect newImageViewFrame = self.imageView.frame;

    // Center horizontally
    if (newImageViewFrame.size.width < CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.bounds)) {
        newImageViewFrame.origin.x = (CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.bounds) - CGRectGetWidth(self.imageView.frame)) / 2;
    }
    else {
        newImageViewFrame.origin.x = 0;
    }

    // Center vertically
    if (newImageViewFrame.size.height < CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollView.bounds)) {
        newImageViewFrame.origin.y = (CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollView.bounds) - CGRectGetHeight(self.imageView.frame)) / 2;
    }
    else {
        newImageViewFrame.origin.y = 0;
    }

    self.imageView.frame = newImageViewFrame;
}
```

So I need it to keep it positioned properly so it doesn't show black borders around the image when repositioned. (That's what the checks in the first block of code are for.)

Basically, I'm curious how to implement functionality like in Photos.app, where on rotate the scrollview intelligently repositions the content so that the middle of the visible content before the rotation is the same post-rotation, so it feels continuous.

Comment: I look forward to seeing the answer... I've burned far too many hours trying to figure out this exact problem.

Comment: Are you trying to show a set of images (thumbnail like) or a single image? You keep referring to the Photos.app but it's not clear if you mean the collection of the image inspection.
If it is a collection of images you are trying to show you definitely want to use a UICollecitonView.
If it is the image view inspection maybe you want to try to get the zoom always stretched in sync with the longer side of the device (height in portrait).

Comment: Sorry, it is indeed for a single image, so to keep with the Photos.app metaphor it would be when you tap on an image in the gallery, the screen that is then presented.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should change the `UIScrollView`'s `contentOffset` property whenever the scrollView is layouting its subviews after its `bounds` value has been changed. Then when the interface orientation will be changed, `UIScrollView`'s `bounds` will be changed accordingly updating the `contentOffset`.

To make things "right" you should subclass `UIScrollView` and make all the adjustments there. This will also allow you to easily reuse your "special" scrollView.

The `contentOffset` calculation function should be placed inside `UIScrollView`'s `layoutSubviews` method. The problem is that this method is called not only when the `bounds` value is changed but also when srollView is zoomed or scrolled. So the `bounds` value should be tracked to hint if the `layoutSubviews` method is called due to a change in `bounds` as a consequence of the orientation change, or due to a pan or pinch gesture.

So the first part of the `UIScrollView` subclass should look like this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Set the prevBoundsSize to the initial bounds, so the first time
        // layoutSubviews is called we won't do any contentOffset adjustments
        self.prevBoundsSize = self.bounds.size;
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (!CGSizeEqualToSize(self.prevBoundsSize, self.bounds.size)) {
        [self _adjustContentOffset];
        self.prevBoundsSize = self.bounds.size;
    }

    [self _centerScrollViewContent];
}
```

Here, the `layoutSubviews` method is called every time the `UIScrollView` is panned, zoomed or its `bounds` are changed. The `_centerScrollViewContent` method is responsible for centering the zoomed view when its size becomes smaller than the size of the scrollView's bounds. And, it is called every time user pans or zooms the scrollView, or rotates the device. Its implementation is very similar to the implementation you provided in your question. The difference is that this method is written in the context of `UIScrollView` class and therefore instead of using `self.imageView` property to reference the zoomed view, which may not be available in the context of `UIScrollView` class, the `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` delegate method is used.

```
- (void)_centerScrollViewContent {
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(viewForZoomingInScrollView:)]) {
        UIView *zoomView = [self.delegate viewForZoomingInScrollView:self];

        CGRect frame = zoomView.frame;
        if (self.contentSize.width < self.bounds.size.width) {
            frame.origin.x = roundf((self.bounds.size.width - self.contentSize.width) / 2);
        } else {
            frame.origin.x = 0;
        }
        if (self.contentSize.height < self.bounds.size.height) {
            frame.origin.y = roundf((self.bounds.size.height - self.contentSize.height) / 2);
        } else {
            frame.origin.y = 0;
        }
        zoomView.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

But the more important thing here is the `_adjustContentOffset` method. This method is responsible for adjusting the `contentOffset`. Such that when `UIScrollView`'s `bounds` value is changed the center point before the change will remain in center. And because of the condition statement, it is called only when `UIScrollView`'s `bounds` is changed (e.g.: orientation change).

```
- (void)_adjustContentOffset {
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(viewForZoomingInScrollView:)]) {
        UIView *zoomView = [self.delegate viewForZoomingInScrollView:self];

        // Using contentOffset and bounds values before the bounds were changed (e.g.: interface orientation change),
        // find the visible center point in the unscaled coordinate space of the zooming view.
        CGPoint prevCenterPoint = (CGPoint){
            .x = (self.prevContentOffset.x + roundf(self.prevBoundsSize.width / 2) - zoomView.frame.origin.x) / self.zoomScale,
            .y = (self.prevContentOffset.y + roundf(self.prevBoundsSize.height / 2) - zoomView.frame.origin.y) / self.zoomScale,
        };

        // Here you can change zoomScale if required
        // [self _changeZoomScaleIfNeeded];

        // Calculate new contentOffset using the previously calculated center point and the new contentOffset and bounds values.
        CGPoint contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
        CGRect frame = zoomView.frame;
        if (self.contentSize.width > self.bounds.size.width) {
            frame.origin.x = 0;
            contentOffset.x = prevCenterPoint.x * self.zoomScale - roundf(self.bounds.size.width / 2);
            if (contentOffset.x < 0) {
                contentOffset.x = 0;
            } else if (contentOffset.x > self.contentSize.width - self.bounds.size.width) {
                contentOffset.x = self.contentSize.width - self.bounds.size.width;
            }
        }
        if (self.contentSize.height > self.bounds.size.height) {
            frame.origin.y = 0;
            contentOffset.y = prevCenterPoint.y * self.zoomScale - roundf(self.bounds.size.height / 2);
            if (contentOffset.y < 0) {
                contentOffset.y = 0;
            } else if (contentOffset.y > self.contentSize.height - self.bounds.size.height) {
                contentOffset.y = self.contentSize.height - self.bounds.size.height;
            }
        }
        zoomView.frame = frame;
        self.contentOffset = contentOffset;
    }
}
```

### Bonus

I've created a working `SMScrollView` class (here is [link to GitHub](https://github.com/smnh/SMScrollView)) implementing the above behavior and additional bonuses:

- You can notice that in Photos app, zooming a photo, then scrolling it to one of its boundaries and then rotating the device does not keep the center point in its place. Instead it sticks the scrollView to that boundary. And if you scroll to one of the corners and then rotate, the scrollView will be stick to that corner as well.
- In addition to adjusting `contentOffset` you may find that you also want to adjust the scrollView's `zoomScale`. For example, assume you are viewing a photo in portrait mode that is scaled to fit the screen size. Then when you rotate the device to the landscape mode you may want to upscale the photo to take advantage of the available space.

Comment: Is it possible to accomplish this without subclassing?

Comment: Yes.

You just need to override the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method of the `UIViewController` that holds your scrollView and move there the code of the `layoutSubviews` method from my example.

Of course you need to replace all the `self` to `self.scrollView`.
And instead getting the `zoomView` using `[self.delegate viewForZoomingInScrollView:self]` you can just use the same view that is returned from that delegate method, in your example it is `self.imageView`.